# Como usar LIKE com OR no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPENDENTE
(
  IdDependente        number(6),
  Matricula           number(6),
  Nome                char(50) NOT NULL,
  dtNascimento        date,

  constraint pk_IdDependente PRIMARY KEY(IdDependente),
  constraint fk_DEPENDENTE foreign key(Matricula) references FUNCIONARIO(Matricula)
);
```

Com os INSERTS :

```
INSERT INTO DEPENDENTE VALUES(1, 1010, 'Francisca', to_date('01/03/1978', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO DEPENDENTE VALUES(2, 2935, 'Joana', to_date('10/08/1984','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO DEPENDENTE VALUES(3, 6987, 'Hugo', to_date('01/09/2009','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO DEPENDENTE VALUES(4, 6987, 'Turine', to_date('10/06/2003','dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO DEPENDENTE VALUES(5, 1234, 'Augusto', to_date('30/06/2005','dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

E com o seguinte SELECT :

```
SELECT 'O dependente ' || InitCap(Nome) || ' é dependente do funcionário de código: ', Matricula FROM Dependente WHERE Nome LIKE ('T%') OR ('A%');
```

Eu quero selecionar somente os dependentes que tenham no começo do nome as letras T ou A, mas ao usar este **SELECT** acima, ele não me retorna o que eu quero. Ele retorna nada. Como posso usar de forma correta o **operador OR** com o **LIKE** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa ajustar seu SQL para as condições:

```
SELECT 'O dependente ' || InitCap(Nome) || ' é dependente do funcionário de código: ', Matricula 
FROM Dependente 
WHERE Nome LIKE 'T%' OR Nome LIKE 'A%';
```

Sempre que há uma nova condição, você repete a coluna a ser condicionada e coloca o operador. `< coluna > < condicao > < referencia >`

Exemplo:

```
WHERE NOME = 'Joaquim' OR NOME <> 'Pedro'
```

Veja mais: [SQL AND, OR and NOT Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado, sabia que estava faltando alguma coisa na condição do LIKE, só não sabia aonde.  +1 e vou dar também como resposta certa, somente tem que esperar um tempo. Novamente, obrigado.